# How to JSON.serialize not including null values

Tags: apex, json, serialize

I have an issue. I have a class with few Strings

```
public class DopplerJSONSerializer {

    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

In some, I need to serialize and use only the **name** String in some methods, and in others I need to use all of them.

Right now if I do for example:

```
public String createListJSON(String listName) {
    DopplerJSONSerializer listWrapper = new DopplerJSONSerializer();
    listWrapper.name = listName;
    String listJSON = JSON.serialize(listWrapper);
    return System.JSON.serialize(listJSON);
}
```

It will return me:

```
{"name":"New List", "email":null}
```

How can I do to not include the non serialized variables into the `JSON.serialize`?

Thank you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the alternative method signature:

```
serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls);
```

Using your code as an example:

```
String listJSON = JSON.serialize(listWrapper, true); // suppress null values
```

Comment: Thank you, dunno why after all the search about json.serialize I didnt saw anywhere the explanation about the boolean in the method,

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of searching for the actual Class name, e.g. 'Salesforce JSON Class'. Those results sometimes lack detailed examples, but I'll often stumble across a little-used but just-what-i-need method or overload. For example [the JSON Class.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)